# Personal collections management software

Tags: osx, collection-manager

I collect both books and stamps, so library management software would be insufficient. I am looking for the following factors in a software package:

- Mac compatible with a desktop client, rather than web-based.
- free or low-cost
- it should be capable of managing multiple libraries and each should be searchable
- It should be able to group sets. I'm picturing stamps of different values within a series (eg. the 1930s-era Canadian definitive stamps, which often came with the same artwork, but different colours and denominations)
- it should include an optional monetary value box for antiquarian or valuable items
- RTL support, specifically for Hebrew

Does anyone know any software which fulfils the above qualifications?

Comment: Hi. I only know of web-based, that can run on any platform. Mentioning this in case requirements have changed since old question.

Comment: @ZZ, I'm partial to desktop clients, because I find it advantageous to have local DB's, in case of internet outages at relevant times (I also have awful bandwidth, far less than I pay Comcast for)

Comment: Ok. But you can run a local webserver on your desktop using something like XAMPP etc. That is what I do on my laptop. Alternative is to run docker locally too.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments above, if you can run docker or webserver on Mac,
you can try: [Koillection](https://github.com/koillection/koillection)

- "a self-hosted collection manager created to keep track of physical (mostly) collections of any kind like books, DVDs, stamps, games"
- It has collections and items management (create, edit, delete).
- Metadata can be added to items etc.

Comment: I've got no idea how to install this and I've downloaded software off GitHub before

Comment: See here for installation on docker or webserver: https://github.com/koillection/koillection/wiki/Installation